# Break text in \item

Tags: enumitem

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=unboxed,leftmargin=4.75cm,labelwidth=!,labelsep=0cm,align=left]
    \item[C]High-level programming language.
\item[Monovalent heat pump system]The entire demand for space heating, ventilation heating and heating of DHW is covered by the heat pump.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

How can i break "Monovalent heat pump system" into two lines? I tried using "style=unboxed" from another tip on stackexchange, but it ditn't change a thing.

"Monovalent heat
pump system"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=4.75cm,labelsep=0cm]
    \item[C]High-level programming language.
\item[Monovalent heat pump system]The entire demand for space heating, ventilation heating and heating of DHW is covered by the heat pump.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a manual break within a structure that allows it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=10em,labelwidth=!,labelsep=0pt,align=left]
  \item[C]High-level programming language.

  \item[\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}Monovalent heat \\ pump system\end{tabular}}]
    The entire demand for space heating, ventilation heating and heating of 
    DHW is covered by the heat pump.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Above I've used `tabular` with a `l`eft-aligned column (and not `\tabcolsep` on the left as a result of `@{}`). `\smash`ing it removes any vertical height/depth component, which would have resulted in line-height problems on the right.

If this is a recurring theme in your setup, you could consider a macro:

```
\newcommand{\stackitemdesc}[1]{\smash{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l} #1 \end{tabular}}}
```